# Twitter Bootstrap misplaced thumbnails

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a profile page with TwiBoo (2.3.2) composed of a row, a span7 for the person projects, then a span5 for buttons:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span7 profile-left">
    <h4><?= $this->lang->line('profile_your_pjts') ?></h4><br>
    <!-- THUMB PROGETTI -->
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <?php foreach($list_pjt as $progetto): ?>
            <li class="span4 pjt-thumb">
              <div class="thumbnail">
              <!-- PROJECT DATA FROM PHP/MYSQL -->
              </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="span5">
    <h4>BUTTONS</h4>
    <!-- SUBSCRIPTION DATA -->
    <!-- BUTTONS -->
</div>
</div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

The problem comes when I add more thumbnails and goes to a new line, where instead of 3 per line I only get 2 from second line on:

[image]

I tried fixing the left-margin with plain css but just moves ALL the thumbs left keeping the same problem. Any idea on why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think wrapping your thumbnail divs (every 3 of them) in a row will make the trick.

Comment: Ok, maybe! But I have a foreach loop inside the class `thumbnail` how can I tell php to loop every three..?

Comment: the simplest/dumbest solution that comes to my mind now is having a flag that you increase at each loop. When it equals to 3 you put the row's closing </div> and then reset it

Comment: I'll try it. Tks for now.